# instance.getChildContext is not a function

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, styled-components

When I upgraded `style-compnent` from `2.1.2` to `4.0.2`. I get the following error. I didn't find any alternative to get the context. How to pass pass context and if this is something not possible with current person than how to return `.dive` without passing context.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key is that `styled-components` 2.x.x supported React v0.14 but 4.x.x switched to React v16.3. Here's a quote from their [doc](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#which-browsers-are-supported):

> - v2.x (React v0.14+): IE9+, all evergreen browsers
> - v3.x (React v0.14+): IE9+, all evergreen browsers
> - v4.x (React v16.3+): IE11, IE 9+ (with Map + Set polyfills), all evergreen browsers

React has changed its Context API and now it doesn't have `getChildContext()` method which returned a context object. You can read more about new React Context API [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Since `ThemeProvider` has `theme` prop (that's the way you pass theme object to it), if you don't want to rewrite much code, you can simply change `getChildContext()` to `props.theme`. Otherwise, you better use the approach *recommended* by [jest-styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components) and write in the following manner, passing your theme directly to your component:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Button theme={theme} />)
```

where, for example

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${props => props.theme.main};
`

const theme = {
  main: 'mediumseagreen',
}
```